# How to send and receive email without exposing email address in PHP

Tags: php, email, symfony, public-key-encryption

I'm developing the feature which offers to establish email communication between buyer and seller, but buyer and seller email ID should not expose to each others.

Comment: and what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create automatically a service that every time a user will register itself, creates an alias (ie.: userid@yourdomain.extension) aswell.
When a user send a mail you can change sender field and when someone replies the alias will send back to original sender the message.

I know, there isn't any line of code but the concept should be clear

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got the solution to my problem. By using **php email parser** and **configuring mail server** it is possible to solve the problem.